# Problema con Bucles Anidados - no progresan

Tags: php, bucles

trataré de explicarme de la mejor manera.

Resulta, que tengo un bucle `for`, el cual esta recorriendo un directorio de rut/fecha (id's).
Dentro de este, el siguiente bucle debe recorrer el directorio de archivos dentro de ese rut/fecha.
Y finalmente, recojo los archivos del directorio final - `"/rut/fecha/archivos.xml"`

El problema que tengo, es que al entrar en el primer bucle y entrar a la primera fecha, luego de revisar esa carpeta, no sigue avanzando a la siguiente como debiese ser.
Si el archivo que obtiene ya existe, el bucle no continua, y la idea es que continue con la siguiente fecha, que es el siguiente directorio a revisar.
He estado intentando arreglar este problema de bucles anidados unos dias, y no se como proceder.

```
for ($i = 2; $i < count($contents); $i++) {                         //Recorro el directorio x fecha
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($contents[$i]));               //Obtengo la fecha y ajusto el formato
    $directorio2 = "/php/boleta/" . $rut . "/" . $fecha;            //Asigno el directorio obtenido
        if (validarFecha($fecha) === true) {                        //Valido que el directorio obtenido sea un formato fecha valido
            $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $directorio2);          //Obtenemos el directorio de los archivos
            if (count($contents) >= 2) {                            //Si existen archivos dentro
                for ($j = 2; $j < count($contents); $j++) {         //Recorremos los archivos //Obtenemos el directorio final
                    $remote_file = "/php/boleta/" . $rut . "/" . $fecha . "/" . $contents[$j];
                    $local_file = "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Documents\\bowa\\temp\\" . $rut . "\\" . $fecha . "\\" . $contents[$j];
                    //Revisar si el .xml ya se ha hecho
                    $xml = file_get_contents($txtLog); //Reviso un log
                    $buscador = $rut . "\\" . $fecha . "\\" . $contents[$j];//Lo comparo con el nombre
                       if (strpos($xml, $buscador) !== false) { //Comparamos el nombre con el log
                          echo "El archivo " . $buscador . ", ya existe </br>";
                       } else {
                          $handle = fopen($local_file, 'w+'); //Acá se descargan los archivos
                          if (ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $remote_file, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {
                              echo "Se ha escrito satisfactoriamente sobre $local_file </br>";
                              fwrite($log, date("H:i:s") . " - Se ha creado el archivo " . str_replace("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Documents\\bowa\\temp\\", "", $local_file) . PHP_EOL);
                              echo "Se ha creado el archivo " . $local_file . " </br>";
                          } else {
                              echo "Ha habido un problema durante la descarga de $remote_file en $local_file </br>";
                          }
                      }
                }
        }
}
```

Este sería el array del directorio que pretendo recorrer.

```
array ( 
    0 => '.', 
    1 => '..', 
    2 => '1990-10-16', 
    3 => '1990-10-26', 
    4 => '2020-09-11', 
    5 => '2020-09-12', 
    6 => '2020-09-15', 
    7 => '2020-09-22', 
    8 => '2020-09-23', 
    9 => '2020-10-09', 
    10 => '2020-10-13', 
    11 => '2020-10-14', 
    12 => '2020-10-147', 
    13 => '2020-10-15', 
    14 => '2020-10-16', 
    15 => '2020-10-17', 
    16 => '2020-10-19', 
    17 => '2020-10-20', 
    18 => '2020-10-22', 
    19 => '2020-10-23', 
    20 => '2020-10-26', 
    21 => 'EQUIPO_1', 
    22 => 'venta_cierre.txt', 
    )
```

Comment: hay una repeticion de variables terribles... esta variable la usas para iterar al principio.. y adentro le cambias el valor? $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $directorio2); eso no puede estar bien...

Comment: Cambiaré $contents, para hacer diferencias de uno y otro, te aviso

Comment: Tal y como mencionas @gbianchi, al parecer el error radicaba en esa variable. Ahora... necesito hacer que este codigo, se detenga luego de terminar de revisar una carpeta de fecha. Es decir, empezamos revisando la `"1990-10-16"` , nos detenemos, y seguimos con `"1990-10-26"`

Comment: no estaria entendiendo tu problema ahora... pero si esta todo el codigo confuso, entonces lleva a mas confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas utilizando la misma variable **$i** en los ciclos anidados. La solución es que el segundo bluce utilices una variable **$j**

```
for ($j = 2; $j < count($contents); $j++)
```

Y otro problema que pudiera haber seria la variable **$contents**  por que dentro de los ciclos cambia de valor

Comment: ufff.. creo que en ese caso, habria que cerrarla como un error tipografico...

Comment: No es eso, he cambiado esos nombres miles de veces, corregire para que no haya confusion. A pesar de que cambie el nombre, el codigo se detiene al  demostrar que dicho archivo ya existe. Pero deberia continuar.

Comment: @Excorpion definitivamente es un error, por que en el ciclo anidado estas incrementando la variable del ciclo padre

Comment: Como dije, he cambiado esos nombres... si quieres te lo repito de nuevo. Ahora mismo tienen el nombre como @AbelValdez lo sugirio, para que puedan descartar

Comment: $Estoy revisando lo que @gbianchi menciona, les aviso que cambios vea

Comment: @AbelValdez Tal y como menciona gbianchi, y agregaste tu, $contents parece haber sido el problema aca. Gracias por la ayuda. La ultima duda que queda, es como hacer que este codigo se detenga al revisar una carpeta de fecha. Es decir, inicia con la primera, se detiene, y mas tarde prosigue con la segunda.

Comment: También los ciclos con la misma variables eran  problema verificarlo para que veas ;)

Comment: Eso esta como tu sugeriste ahora. Lo que falta, es poder detener el codigo, luego de revisar una carpeta, ya que si revisa todo siempre, superara el tiempo de ejecucion.

Comment: if ($fecha  === strtotime('1990-10-16')){
   break;
}

Comment: No pero, la idea es que pare solo, por cada carpeta que encuentre, y reanude mas tarde.